# How to make Photoshop Effects on Adobe Illustrator unlimited?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, cc-2014, illustrator-effects

When I apply **Blur > Gaussian Blur** on this shape,
[image]

this is the result:
[image]

The result is that the **Gaussian Blur** doesn't appear completely, and borders indicated below limits it.
[image]

How can I make the **"Gaussian Blur" Effect** appear completely in Adobe Illustrator CC 2014?

Comment: A radial gradient is more appropriate than a huge blur effect. There's no reason you should need a blur that large in Illustrator. Illustrator is *not* Photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under **Effect → Document Raster Effects Settings...** You have a option called Add <kbd>???</kbd> around object. Increase this value, this slows down rasterization as a side effect.

[image: raster effects option]

**Image 1:** The raster effects option dialog

Obviously you can not make this unlimited but big enough for your purposes.